# getStringExtra thows NullPointerException (name is null)

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using a LocalBroadcastManager to broadcast an intent and I want to put a string extra in this intent.

Broadcast code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strValue);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(action));
```

Receiver code:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(MusicService.action);
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(MusicService.action)) {
                updateUI(intent.getStringExtra("STRING_I_NEED")); // THIS IS THE LINE THAT GIVES ME THE ERROR        
            }
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

I'm getting the error NullPointerException name is null.

Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are here creating two intents..so one intent doesn't have any Extras data..

so change this line

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(action));
```

into

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: This is the answer! Thanks for the help! I'll accept your answer as soon as possible

Comment: There is a time to accept the answer. You were superfast! hahaha

Comment: If you simply do intent.getExtras().getString(key), you run the risk of nullpointerexecptions. Also, it is really wordy and gets annoying to type.
Use https://github.com/beplaya/Wagon for your extras. Way easier.

Answer (score 0):

try this way `intent.getExtras().getString(key)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this wasn't the problem.